# How can I include CLHEP libraries in standard .cpp files when compiling with g++?

Tags: c++, gcc

I installed CLHEP according to the instructions from the README.md file downloaded from http://proj-clhep.web.cern.ch/proj-clhep/. However, when I try to include any of its headers in my standard cpp files, I run into errors with the include statements. For example, my code contains

## include "CLHEP/Random/Random.h"

which gives me the error

"main.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'CLHEP/Random/Random.h' file not found"

I can get rid of this issue by brute force if I just modify the line above to include the full path to Random.h, but then I'd have to go through all the header files and make the same adjustment which seems too tedious to be the smartest solution.

I know I can also include the include/ directory with the gcc -I flag, but when I tried this I would get a large amount of text followed by "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

I'm happy to provide more code and/or error messages if it helps solve the issue.

Comment: You need to a) tell your compiler where to find headers (`-I`) and b) also where to find runtime libraries (`-L`). The compiler can't magically guess where your stuff is.

Comment: Thanks. I was including the -I statement before but would get a long error message (same when I include -L). This is what it says at the end of the message: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). The -I links to the build/include directory and the -L to build/lib.